# Code in FOR loop not executed

Tags: android, gson, progressdialog

I have a ProgressDialog that retrieves in background data from database by executing php script.
I'm using gson Google library. php script is working well when executed from browser:

```
{"surveys":[{"id_survey":"1","question_survey":"Are you happy with the actual government?","answer_yes":"50","answer_no":"20"}],"success":1}
```

However, ProgressDialog background treatment is not working well:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.4/tn_surveys/get_all_surveys.php";

            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.d("GETREQUEST",getRequest.toString());

            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                Log.d("URL1",url);

                HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
                Log.d("GETRESPONSE",getResponse.toString());
                final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                Log.d("STATUSCODE",Integer.toString(statusCode));
                Log.d("HTTPSTATUSOK",Integer.toString(HttpStatus.SC_OK));
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
                    return null;
                }

                HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                Log.d("RESPONSEENTITY",getResponseEntity.toString());
                InputStream httpResponseStream = getResponseEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("HTTPRESPONSESTREAM",httpResponseStream.toString());
                Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpResponseStream);

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                this.response = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, Response.class);

            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
            }

            return null;
        }
    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.d("HELLO","HELLO");
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                Log.d("STRINGBUILDER","STRINGBUILDER");
                for (Survey survey : this.response.data) {
                    String x= survey.getQuestion_survey();
                    Log.d("QUESTION",x);
                    builder.append(String.format("<br>ID Survey: <b>%s</b><br> <br>Question: <b>%s</b><br> <br>Answer YES: <b>%s</b><br> <br>Answer NO: <b>%s</b><br><br><br>", survey.getId_survey(), survey.getQuestion_survey(),survey.getAnswer_yes(),survey.getAnswer_no()));

                }

                Log.d("OUT FOR","OUT");
                capitalTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }
```

HELLO Log is displayed.
STRINGBUILDER Log is displayed.
QUESTION Log is NOT displayed.
OUT FOR Log is displayed.

Survey Class:

```
public class Survey {

    int id_survey;
    String question_survey;
    int answer_yes;
    int answer_no;

    public Survey() {

        this.id_survey = 0;
        this.question_survey = "";
        this.answer_yes=0;
        this.answer_no=0;
    }

    public int getId_survey() {
        return id_survey;
    }

    public String getQuestion_survey() {
        return question_survey;
    }

    public int getAnswer_yes() {
        return answer_yes;
    }

    public int getAnswer_no() {
        return answer_no;
    }


}
```

Response Class:

```
public class Response {

    ArrayList<Survey> data;

    public Response() {
        data = new ArrayList<Survey>();
    }
}
```

Any help please concerning WHY the FOR loop is not executed.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any help please concerning WHY the FOR loop is not executed.

Simply put: `data` is empty. (So there is nothing for the loop to iterate over...)

Try something like this, from [GSON's documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html):

```
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
 List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();
 target.add("blah");

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
 List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

I haven't used GSON myself, but there are other examples of how to read lists:

- [Android gson deserialization into list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7959157/1267661)
- [GSON : custom object deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8533020/1267661)

Comment: but data become not empty in that line : `this.response = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, Response.class);` no? So there is "surveys" objects there.

Comment: That surely was a blind guess :D because i can't convert from Response to ArrayList. But please look at Response constructor, when there is a response instance, data arraylist is not empty, it will stores surveys data.

Comment: In Response's constructor, you create an empty list with `new ArrayList<Survey>();` but you never pass it any data...

Comment: Sorry sam but i do not understand the use of that code? To store "surveys" in data? thank you.

Comment: SAM i used that url php file in an exactly same other project and that's working well `http://api.androidsmith.com/capitals.php`. I think that data is not retrieved when executing php script. Please see how i execute my php file perhaps there is something wrong.

Comment: I'm reading about GSON's `fromJSON()` since I haven't worked with it. From what I can tell your class `Survey` does not match the JSON element `"surveys"`, change the JSON element to match the class name.

Comment: But it's matching the class name. No? I'm not using "surveys" anywhere.

Comment: You are using "surveys" here: `{"surveys":[{"id_survey":"1"...` and `Survey` does not match `surveys`.

Comment: `surveys` is the table name in database.

Comment: So i rename class Survey to Surveys. Or i change table database name to "Survey". That's what you'd like to tell please?

Answer (score 0):

Your onPostExecute takes in a parameter called `result`. Your for loop iterates over the elements in an instance variable called `response`. Are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: It's not clear that referring to instance variables updated by the execute phase is going to work. It's not one of the specifically allowed operations of the AsyncTask class. You could define the result of the execute phase as a Survey and that would appear as the parameter to onPostExecute.

Comment: Any code suggestion please? Because it seems that data variable is empty for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much good at JSON. I'd print out the JSON data and see what it looks like.